# SELECT 2 TABLAS ORACLE 8

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo la limitación de Oracle 8 que no toma inner join . En la tabla CABECERA tengo el IDENTIFICADOR que es único, pero en la tabla DETALLES que serian los renglones de cada venta puede haber 1 o mas líneas, y las necesito unificadas con el IDENTIFICADOR correspondiente.
No me funciona , me lista el IDENTIFICADOR tantas veces como lineas hay en DETALLES.

```
  SELECT a.IDENTIFICADOR, SUM(a.SUBTOTAL), SUM(b.IMPORTE)AS Total  
  FROM CABECERA a, DETALLES b 
  WHERE
  a.IDENTIFICADOR=b.IDENTIFICADOR AND 
  a.FEC_EMISION=TO_DATE('15/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') 
  GROUP BY a.IDENTIFICADOR,a.SUBTOTAL,b.IMPORTE
```

Ayuda please !!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un error de concepto en el `GROUP BY`. Debes poner solo `GROUP BY a.IDENTIFICADOR` para que te agrupe los cálculos por identificador.

```
SELECT a.IDENTIFICADOR, SUM(a.SUBTOTAL), SUM(b.IMPORTE)AS Total 
FROM CABECERA a, DETALLES b 
WHERE
a.IDENTIFICADOR=b.IDENTIFICADOR AND 
a.FEC_EMISION=TO_DATE('15/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') 
GROUP BY a.IDENTIFICADOR
```

Comment: Hola si, disculpas, hice pruebas varias y quedó mal ...

Answer (score 0):

No agrupes por columnas calculadas puestas regresan un único renglón y dichos valores no son los que originalmente tienes en tus tablas.

Entonces tú `GROUP BY` solo debe quedar como

```
GROUP BY a.IDENTIFICADOR....
```

Para que de esta forma:

- Tu `GROUP BY` reducirá todos los registros a N filas agrupandolos por aquellos que sean iguales
- Las dos funciones de agregación que tienes reducirán los montos en este caso sumando los de acuerdo con la condición dual de tu `WHERE`

**Referencia**

- [Oracle docs `GROUP BY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html)